# SQL WHERE clause for column all capitalized

Tags: sql, sql-server

`table_beatles` contains the following data in column `name`.

- John
- PAUL
- george
- RINGO

In MS-SQL is there anyway to get any item which is all caps? eg

```
SELECT * FROM table_beatles where name is (AllCaps SYNTAX HERE)
```

to return PAUL and RINGO.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How you do this depends on the collation used. If you have a case insensitive collation, you are asking SQL to treat lower and upper case the same. So you may need to do this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table_beatles
WHERE   UPPER(name) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
             = name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

This forces SQL to use a case sensitive (CS) comparison for the equality check. If you already have a case sensitive collation, then you can omit the two `COLLATE` parts of this. But given you've asked the question, I'm guessing you haven't.

Comment: Is should have worked that out in about 2 seconds :\ Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a case sensitive search. There are many methods explained here: [Case sensitive search in SQL Server queries](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_beatles where UPPER(name) = name
```

Comment: Yes, used it last week in some project on a database set up by other persons. Must have been a case sensitive collation there.